# Like totally amazing interchangeable sister outfit accessory swapping or whatever

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

OMG, me and my sister are like total BFFs and we share clothes like *all the time*!  We soooo have the same sense of style and we borrow stuff from each other like every single second!

We don't even care, like, who was the last to borrow what from who or whatever.  We can work anything into our outfits no matter what and make like a totally new outfit every time!  And we always look so cute!

Seriously, the one thing is, we like never ever *ever* wear the same outfit twice.  That would be so embarrassing you could just *die*!  You know what I mean?

Anyway, check it out:

```
Take sisters CASTLE & OATHS through 6 more outfits
by lending/borrowing one "accessory" (letter) at a time


------------------------------------

Solution:


CASTLE          OATHS
  |           .   |
  |         .     |
  |        S      |
  |      .        |
  v    .          v
CASTLES         OATH
  |    .          |
  |      .        |
  |        L      |
  |          .    |
  v            .  v
CASTES          LOATH
  |    .          |
  |      .        |
  |        E      |
  |          .    |
  v            .  v
CASTS           LOATHE
  |           .   |
  |         .     |
  |        O      |
  |      .        |
  v    .          v
COASTS          LATHE
  |    .          |
  |      .        |
  |        S      |
  |          .    |
  v            .  v
COATS           LATHES
  |    .          |
  |      .        |
  |        O      |
  |          .    |
  v            .  v
CATS            LOATHES
```

(At this point, I typically remind solvers that my puzzles only use well-known words, but these tandem chains are difficult to construct without a *few* near-slang words.  So be prepared for an occasional ding, ting, zing, bling, cred, or dang.)

See if you can help these 5 sister pairs change their outfits:

```
1.  Take sisters SAND & PILE through 7 more outfits by lending/borrowing one "accessory" (letter) at a time


2.  Take sisters TRIED & GINS through 7 more outfits by lending/borrowing one "accessory" (letter) at a time


3.  Take sisters BEERS & TAPS through 7 more outfits by lending/borrowing one "accessory" (letter) at a time


4.  Take sisters SCORED & CUP through 8 more outfits by lending/borrowing one "accessory" (letter) at a time


5.  Take sisters COOTS & BATS through 8 more outfits by lending/borrowing one "accessory" (letter) at a time
```

---

Epilogue:

Extra super double credit to @osdavison @Brandon_J and @Dolgubon for coming up with longer chains than I had prescribed!

See the sequel [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83251/like-totally-amazing-interchangeable-sister-outfits-ii-the-revenge)

Comment: This is likely irrelevant, but no, I don't know what you mean :) Very nice puzzle!

Comment: Do you accept partial answers, on only one solution for all five?

Comment: @PartyHatPanda — Based on past observation, I would suggest posting whatever you can as soon as you can.  Suggestions and corrections will be made, others might borrow from you with credit, you might borrow from others, and eventually a consensus will emerge under one voice.

Comment: @Brandon_J — Hey, you took away my graph-theory tag!  That's what I use to construct the puzzles, and, whether they know it or not, that's what solvers use to solve them...

Comment: @SlowMagic whoops sorry - the tag wiki didn't seem to match the puzzle. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: I think there's a difference between a question that _can be modelled_ using graph theory and a question _about_ graph theory, and to my mind this question is definitely only in the first of those categories. For the avoidance of doubt, I totally agree that what you're effectively doing when solving it is looking for long paths in a certain graph, but I don't think that's really enough to make it deserve the graph-theory tag.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan — Thanks for clarifying.  Always testing the boundaries!

Comment: This is likely irrelevant, but, *Like totally* not excessively long wordplay puzzle writing *or whatever* :) Very nice puzzle! @Brandon_J

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Completed answer:

SAND & PILE (I can get 8, one more than expected)

> AND & PILES --> LAND & PIES --> LANDS & PIE --> LADS & PINE --> LEADS & PIN --> LEAD & PINS --> LED & PAINS --> SLED & PAIN

TRIED & GINS (7, as expected) - partial credit to **OmegaKrypton** - please go upvote his answer!

> TIED & GRINS --> TIE & GRINDS --> TIES & GRIND --> TIDES & GRIN --> IDES & GRINT --> IDE & GRINTS --> NIDE & GRITS --> NIDES & GRIT

BEERS & TAPS (7) - **osdavison** has an *independent solution* with *11* words; please go upvote it.

> BEES & TRAPS --> BEETS & RAPS --> BESETS & RAP --> BESTS & REAP --> BEASTS & REP --> BEATS & REPS --> BETS & REAPS

SCORED & CUP (8, as expected) - credit to **Gareth McCaughan** - please go upvote his answer!

> CORED & CUPS --> CRED & COUPS --> CURED & COPS --> CURD & COPSE --> CURDS & COPE --> CUDS & COPER --> CUD & COPERS --> CRUD & COPES

COOTS & BATS (8, as expected) - **PartyHatPanda** has an *independent* solution - go upvote it!

> COTS & BOATS --> COSTS & BOAT --> COASTS & BOT --> COAST & BOTS --> CAST & BOOTS --> CASTS AND BOOT --> CATS & BOOST --> CAT & BOOSTS

Comment: I should have just posted mine too instead of asking! Good solve though

Comment: @PartyHatPanda well, he didn't specify, so I just went ahead. The more, the merrier, though!

Comment: @SlowMagic how am I doing? Do "rep" and "reps" count in your book?

Comment: Sure, given my caveat about the possibility of near-slang, I'll take REP.  FYI for further exploration, there exists another path through BEERS & TAPS without any hint of slang.

Comment: FYI for anybody, there's definitely another solution to TRIED & GINS...

Comment: @SlowMagic do I need to find it?

Comment: No, but anyone else who is interested should know that there is still room to help out.

Answer (score 11):

Improved solution for BEERS & TAPS (<strike>9</strike> edit: now up to 11)

Based off of @Brandon_J's solution

> BEES & T**R**APS
>  BEE**T**S & RAPS
>  BETS & R**E**APS
>  BE**A**TS & REPS
>  BEA**S**TS & REP
>  BESTS & RE**A**P
>  BES**E**TS & RAP
>  BESET & RA**S**P
>  BEET & RASP**S**
>  BE**R**ET & ASPS
>  BERET**S** & ASP

Comment: Excellent work.

Answer (score 10):

16 for Sand Pile, though Id and ids may be a bit of a stretch.

> SAND PILE > AND PILES > LAND PIES > LANDS PIE > LADS PINE > LEADS PIN > LEAD PINS > LED PAINS > LIED PANS > LID PANES > SLID PANE > SLIDE PAN > SIDE PLAN > IDE PLANS > ID PLANES > IDS PLANE > IS PLANED

20, if we allow acronyms, and one word from music.

> SAND PILE > AND PILES > LAND PIES > LANDS PIE > LANS PIED > LAN SPIED > LA SPINED > LAD SPINE > LADS PINE > LEADS PIN > LEAD PINS > LED PAINS > LIED PANS > LID PANES > SLID PANE > SLIDE PAN > SIDE PLAN > IDE PLANS > ID PLANES > IDS PLANE > IS PLANED

A slightly different Scored and Cups, but still at 8:

> SCORED CUP > CORED CUPS > CRED COUPS > CURED COPS > CUED CORPS > CUD CORPSE > CUDS COPER > CURDS COPE > CURD COPES

Coots and Bats, 12, four more than expected. For this one, following the hint in the comments, I drew a graph, and found the longest path following the rules. There's a lot of cycles and relations, so the graph helped. I did use the other two answers to make sure I hadn't missed any words.

> COOTS BATS > SCOOTS BAT > SCOOT BAST > SCOT BOAST > COT BOASTS > COST BOATS > COSTS BOAT > COASTS BOT > COATS BOTS > CATS BOOTS > CAT BOOSTS > CAST BOOST > CASTS BOOT

Here's a few partial chains for Sand Pile which I couldn't fit in, but which might be helpful for someone trying to go further.

> lads pine > lad spine > lead spin >  led Spain > sled pain

.

> lads pine > lad spine > lead spin > plead sin > pleads in > leads pin > lead pins > led pains (almost able to fit this right in for 21, but there's lead spin and lead pins)

.

> lads pine > lad spine > lead spin > plead sin > pleads in > pleas din > Plea dins

Comment: Unfortunately, you repeat some words in the SAND PILE sequence, which is not allowed by the OP. still, +1

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I edited to remove the doubled word, and added another one, so still the same total. I think I got all of them, but let me know if there's one I missed

Comment: Wow!  (1) Great long chain!  I have no problem with ID and IDS.  Those are perfectly cromulent Freudian words!  I understand now why this solution did not present itself to me — because I had taken IDE and IDES out of my solving dictionary as being too... literary.  (2) A very similar solution has COPSE in place of COPERS.  Then again, maybe COPSE is also too literary...  (3) Thank you for using graph theory!!  I think that justifies my use of the graph-theory tag, don't you agree?  And I learned a new word: BAST.

Comment: also CUD CORPSE > CUDS COPER doesn't work because you switch some letters.

Answer (score 9):

I can do 8 from SCORED and CUP:

> scored cup
>  cored cups
>  cred coups
>  cured cops
>  curd copse
>  curds cope
>  cuds coper
>  cud copers
>  crud copes

Answer (score 8):

Possibly a stretch with some slangish words, but
COOTS & BATS

> COTS & BOATS -> COT & BOASTS -> SCOT & BOAST -> SCOOT & BAST -> SCOOTS & BAT -> SCOTS & BOAT -> ASCOTS & BOT -> ASCOT & BOTS

Comment: @Brandon_J I always thought of an ascot as a [scarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascot_tie)

Comment: Hmm. Nice! I got it without stretches, I think

Comment: Nice one with the ascot!  We don't see nearly enough of that word, or the thing itself!  Interesting aside:  I have removed all proper nouns from my own solving dictionary, so I didn't even see this particular solution (because it depends on SCOT and SCOTS).  Thanks for presenting this novel approach!

Answer (score 8):

**17!**
SAND & PILE (adding on to @Brandon_J's answer, go upvote it!)

***beware of lots of stretches (with links)***

> SAND PILE --> AND PILES --> LAND PIES --> LANDS PIE --> LADS PINE --> LEADS PIN --> LEAD PINS --> LED PAINS --> LIED PANS --> LID PANES --> SLID PANE --> SLIDE PAN --> SIDE PLAN --> IDE PLANS --> [PIDE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pide) & LANS *(as in LANs, local area network)* --> [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelvic_inflammatory_disease) LANES --> [PIDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_information_system) LANE

10 NOW!
COOTS & BATS (adding on to @Brandon_J's answer, go upvote it!)

> COTS & BOATS --> COSTS & BOAT --> COASTS & BOT --> COAST & BOTS --> CAST & BOOTS --> CASTS AND BOOT --> CATS & BOOST --> CAT & BOOSTS --> COAT & [BOSTS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bosts) --> COATS & BOST

TIED & GRINS (first half from @Brandon_J)

> TIED & GRINS --> TIE & GRINDS --> TIES & GRIND --> TIDES & GRIN --> IDES & GRINT --> IDE & GRINTS --> NIDE & GRITS --> [NIDES](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/NIDES) & GRIT

SCORED & CUP (partial)

> SCORED & CUP --> CORED & CUPS -->[CRED](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cred) & [COUPS](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coup) --> CURED & [SCOP](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scop) --> CURD & SCOPE --> CUR & SCOPED --> CURS & COPED

Past attempt:

> CORD & [CUPES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupes)// CURDS & [SOPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sope)// CURSED & COP

Comment: Hmmm..Very good, but I dunno how I like cupes, grint, and nides. @SlowMagic ?

Comment: I'll admit that I had to look up all three of those in my unabridged doorstop dictionary.  I'll also admit that I couldn't find "cupes" and "grint", although "nide" is a nest or brood of pheasants.  Who knew?!

Answer (score 4):

Here's some alternative outfits for Tried and Gins

> tied & g**r**ins > tie & grin**d**s > ti**n**e & grids > tin**g**e & rids > **s**tinge & rid > sting & rid**e** > ting & ride**s** > tin & ridges

Comment: Yes, this is very similar to the solution I have.  (Mine skips over "stinge" and gets an extra one at the end with TINS.)