# Like totally amazing interchangeable sister outfits II: The Revenge

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

The sisters have learned a few lessons from their recent [debut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/82054/like-totally-amazing-interchangeable-sister-outfit-accessory-swapping-or-whateve).  They are now ruthlessly efficient outfit-swapping machines.  (You know, sort of like Valley Girl Terminators...)

They can now sustain swapping chains of 21 or more outfit pairs.  In some cases, the sisters have completely exchanged outfits by the end.

No sister may wear an outfit that she has previously worn.

See if you can solve this one:

> Take sisters EAR & TASTES through at least 21 more outfits by lending/borrowing one "accessory" (letter) at a time.

You will be revered eternally if you can end with the sisters' outfits completely exchanged.  (I.e., ending with TASTES & EAR.)  But this is not a requirement.

I am accepting TASER as a brand name which has come into common usage.  Otherwise, all words are well-known.  No need to reach for the dictionary.

Comment: Is that (unique outfit) pairs, or unique (outfit pairs)? That is, do you still require that no sister wear the same outfit twice?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan — Same rules as before.  No sister may wear an outfit that she has previously worn.  (However, it is possible that sister A might wear something that sister B wore previously, and sister B might wear something that sister A wore previously.)

Comment: The parenthetical bit was clear enough from the suggestion of ending with TASTES/EAR :-).

Comment: Drat...there are _so many_ promising dead ends!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

21 changes ending with reversal:

> ear tastes 0
>  sear taste 1
>  sea taster 2
>  seat taser 3
>  eat tasers 4
>  at teasers 5
>  art teases 6
>  tart eases 7
>  tarts ease 8
>  tars tease 9
>  tears teas 10
>  teas tears 11
>  tease tars 12
>  ease tarts 13
>  eases tart 14
>  teases art 15
>  teasers at 16
>  tasers eat 17
>  taser seat 18
>  taster sea 19
>  taste sear 20
>  tastes ear 21

Comment: Well, then, I guess you will be revered eternally :). Nice solve; very fast, accurate etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not wild about TEASERS -- I mean, it's definitely a word, but it seems to me rather an ungainly one.

Comment: Maybe not as 'people who tease,' but it's being used a lot in entertainment for the types of trailer that come out before the 'true' full-length trailer.

Comment: Also, brain “teasers,” which this very site has a lot of

Comment: 11-20 is just a reflection of 1-10, which seems to violate at least the spirit of `21 or more unique outfit pairs`.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaser_and_the_Firecat. Number 2 on the Billboard Pop Album chart in 1972. If it’s good enough for Cat Stevens in the singular, it’s good enough for me in the plural.

Comment: Ha, completely failed to think of movie teasers and brain teasers. Yeah, I retract my lack of enthusiasm for that word.

Comment: @asgallant I don't think it violates the spirit -- we're _looking_ for a symmetrical ending, after all, and what could be a more symmetrical way of getting there? But if SlowMagic says that a less symmetrical solution would be better, perhaps someone will post one.

Comment: Nice work!  This is one of the solutions I have.  BTW, I didn't bat an eye at TEASER and TEASERS, but last week I spent a good few minutes staring at REENLIST for some reason...  Weird how some words in isolation can suddenly look kinda funny.

Comment: @asgallant — I appreciate your point, and I have edited the question to clarify.  When I originally wrote it, I was thinking in terms of combinatorics: the sisters are distinguishable, and ordering of the 2-tuple matters.  So an "outfit pair" is an ordered pair, thus the outfit pair (X,Y) is distinct from the outfit pair (Y,X).  Only that any particular sister cannot repeat an outfit she has worn  before (otherwise we would have chains with endless loops).

Comment: @asgallant — As for the symmetry of the solution, that is somewhat expected given that it starts with (EAR, TASTES) and ends with (TASTES, EAR).  There are some variant solutions which are marginally less symmetrical, but they are basically this.  I have some other chains lying around which are much less symmetrical, but they are tedious and I thought this one was so much more delightful.

Comment: Fair enough. I spent a couple hours trying to come up with an asymmetric solution and didn't succeed.